# Solr Parent Blockjoin with Filter Query on Children

Tags: solr

Is there a good way to do Solr Parent blockjoins with filter queries on children (i.e. the results of the children query set affect the filter on the children of the filter query)?

Solr has a convenient way of doing filter queries on the result set of parent block joins. E.g.

```
q={!parent which=doc_type:parent}content:dog
&fq={!parent which=doc_type:parent}comment:cat
```

But note that this only filters the **parent** result set based on the results of the children. The full children result set is used for the filter both times.

To clarify, if I insert a document with child A and B

```
{
    "doc_type":"parent",
    "id":"1",
    __children__: [
        {
            "id":"A"
        },
        {
            "id":"B"
        }
    ]
}
```

I wish to be able to search for A and filter B to get nothing in the results, since the child doc match for id was on A (not B). Current behavior is that the result comes back since both children are searched in either the query or the filter query.
[image: Solr Search Example 1]

To contrast, normal document filter behavior is to remove non-matching documents from the result set. E.g. if there are two documents with id 1 & 2 and I search id:1 with a filter query of id:2 I will get no documents back.

I know that the proper behavior can be achieved using a single query:

```
q={!parent which=doc_type:parent}id:A AND id:B
```

But there are certain cases where a filter query may be preferred esp. in a situation where multiple parent block-join queries are used in the q (or fq) value and you wish to filter over them with an fq.

If there is no current implementation for this in the current solr project, I would appreciate guidance on if this would be reasonable to implement.

Thank you!

Comment: This helps explain that the filter is done in the parent document space: https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/join/src/java/org/apache/lucene/search/join/ToParentBlockJoinQuery.java#L53